# Setting titles programmatically in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Working with `UITabBarController`, I am facing the following issue.
I want to have a given string as the title for all my view controllers, in each tab. This is apparently not possible to set within the `storyboard`.

By searching the net I have found this almost-working solution. Putting the following type of code in each of the separate view controllers.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem;
    tabBarItem=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                             image:[self imageFromText:@"My Tab Title"
                                                              withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]] tag:0];
    self.tabBarItem=tabBarItem;
}
```

The problem is: all the title are only set to what I want only when the user has tapped all the tabs.

This of course is not a good permanent solution. I need to have all the titles appear properly when the app starts.

Comment: I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it in the **AppDelegate**.

e.g. if you have 3 `TabBarIcons`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Your "];
    [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"title "];
    [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"here"];

    [[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem] setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"first"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic]];
    [[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tabBarItem] setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"second"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic]];
    [[[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem] setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"third"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I ended up by subclassing UITabBarController. But what I've done looks similar to your suggestion.